# Databricks - Photon ran out of memory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to read a directory of json files in S3 using databricks spark with photon enabled. The size of the json directory is approx. 100 - 120 GB

```
   df = (spark
         .read
         .option("multiline", True)
         .json(json_dir_path)
         .schema(json_schema)
        )

df.write.format('delta').saveAsTable("table_name")
```

This throws an error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError: Photon ran out of memory while executing this query.
Photon failed to reserve 1728.0 MiB for simdjson internal usage, in SimdJsonReader, in JsonFileScanNode(id=3618, output_schema=[string, string, array<struct<string, string, string, string>>, string, string, ... 1 more]), in task.
```

Whereas, this works when the photon is not enabled. Is there any configuration should be specified when using photon for processing huge json files in databricks ?

Answer (score 0):

We recently had an issue with a cluster configuration that enabled Photon.  We started running out of memory as well.  We "fixed" it by adding more memory and reducing the number of executors, so each one had more available memory. But in retrospect, for that particular workflow, it would have been better to just leave photon off.

Comment: `it would have been better to just leave photon off.` Why is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

We ran into a similar situation with a SQL query that ran fine on an XL Serverless Warehouse 6 weeks ago, but now won't run even on a 3XL or 4XL Serverless Warehouse despite negligible increase in table size (from 3.2  to 3.3 TB).  The error (after about 30 seconds) was:

```
Photon ran out of memory while executing this query.
Photon failed to reserve 763.6 MiB for var-len data, in ShuffleExchangeSinkNode(id=1676, output_schema=[double, timestamp, timestamp, double, double, ... 17 more]), in task.
Memory usage:
Total task memory (including non-Photon): 1719.2 MiB
task: allocated 868.5 MiB, tracked 1719.2 MiB, untracked allocated 0.0 B, peak 1982.9 MiB
BufferPool: allocated 8.3 MiB, tracked 128.0 MiB, untracked allocated 0.0 B, peak 128.0 MiB
DataWriter: allocated 0.0 B, tracked 0.0 B, untracked allocated 0.0 B, peak 0.0 B
FileScanNode(id=1660, output_schema=[double, double, timestamp, double, double, ... 13 more]): allocated 6.1 MiB, tracked 737.1 MiB, untracked allocated 0.0 B, peak 737.8 MiB
BufferPool: allocated 6.1 MiB, tracked 737.1 MiB, untracked allocated 0.0 B, peak 737.1 MiB
```

In the end, we got the query working by using a smaller sized cluster (without Photon) (cluster sizing approximately equal to an XL Serverless warehouse).  However since this was a straight forward SQL query, we'd much prefer to have this working on a Serverless Warehouse where we have better access to higher performance compute (and better logging).