# Photon ran out of memory while executing this query. Photon failed to reserve 349.4 MiB for hash table var-len key data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I am trying to run below code with Delta Live Tables.

```
@dlt.view
def data():
    return (spark.readStream
        .option("skipChangeCommits", "true")
        .format("delta")
        .table("table")
        .withColumnRenamed("col","col_name")

    )
    
schema = StructType([
    StructField("col_name", StringType(), True),
  ])
dlt.create_streaming_table(
    name="table",
    spark_conf={},
    table_properties={"quality":"bronze"},
    partition_cols=["col"],
    schema=schema
    )
dlt.apply_changes(
    target="table",
    source="data",
    keys=["userId"],
    sequence_by=col("col_name"),
    stored_as_scd_type=1 
)
```

While running this I get error

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError: Photon ran
> out of memory while executing this query. Photon failed to reserve
> 349.6 MiB for hash table var-len key data, in ParquetDictionaryEncoder, in FileWriterNode(id=34323,
> output_schema=[]), in task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By increasing the memory allocation per executor and reducing the total number of executors, each executor will have more memory available.

You can do this by setting the `spark.databricks.delta.photon.buffer.maxMemory configuration` property to a higher value.
You can add the following line of code before creating the dlt object:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.photon.buffer.maxMemory", "8g")
```

I have tried the below:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.spark.driver.memory", "8g")
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.spark.executor.memory", "8g")
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.photon.buffer.maxMemory", "8g")
```

**Results:**

```
driver_memory = spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.spark.driver.memory")
executor_memory = spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.spark.executor.memory")
photon_memory = spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.delta.photon.buffer.maxMemory")
print("Driver Memory:", driver_memory)
print("Executor Memory:", executor_memory)
print("Photon Buffer Max Memory:", photon_memory)
```

```
Driver Memory: 8g
Executor Memory: 8g
Photon Buffer Max Memory: 8g
```

**Reference:**
[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77287688/databricks-photon-ran-out-of-memory) link